# Change menu language in Red Dead Redemption 2

Tags: pc, red-dead-redemption-2

How can I set my menu language to english? I don't see any option ingame for changing the language. The language of the Rockstar launcher is already set to English. Adding the launcher argument '-uilanguage "american"' or '-uilanguage "english"' did not work, either.

Do I have to change the language of Windows?

Comment: What language are you seeing?  Did you purchase it through the Rockstar launcher?

Comment: @Steve-o169: I purchased it on GMG and activated it in the Rockstar launcher. I see the menu in German, the same language as my OS.

Comment: @Steve-o169: Thanks, I set the launcher language to German, restarted the launcher, set the language back to English and restarted the launcher again. Now the ingame menu is in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this source](https://www.usgamer.net/articles/red-dead-redemption-2-pc-subtitles-language-change-guide), the game language can be changed in the Rockstar Launcher settings.  Select settings and change the launcher language to your preferred language.  You then need to restart the launcher and you may need to restart multiple times -- alternating between the current language and your preferred language. You should then be able to run the game with the correct language for the UI/subtitles.

If all this fails, you can also change the language set on your PC to the desired language and restart the launcher and game.